# Получение файла .ovpn через subprocess.communicate()

Tags: python, openvpn, subprocess, stdin

Пытаюсь автоматизировать получение файла-конфигурации.ovpn
На локальной машине скрипт работает, на сервере зависает.

АЛГОРИТМ ПРОГРАММЫ
После того как установил openvpn повторно запускаю установочный файл командой:
sudo bash /home/$USER/openvpn-install.sh
Отвечаю на вопрос добавить пользователя # 1
Отвечаю на вопрос имя для пользователя # hero
Готово, терминал показывает где хранится файл.

Теперь я пытаюсь автоматизировать процесс на сервере(Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS), вручную все работает:

```
import subprocess

print('write_command')
command=['sudo bash /home/$USER/openvpn-install.sh']
print('start pr')
pr=subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
out=pr.communicate("1\nhero\n")[0]
print(out)
```

На локальной машине этот код запускается и выполняется без проблем.
На сервере все останавливается после print('start pr')

Есть подозрение что конфликт работы communicate через ssh.
Вручную на сервере все работает.
Также я у меня получилось автоматизировать через readline stdin stdout задуманное построчно на сервере:

```
import subprocess

print('write_command')
command=['sudo bash /home/$USER/openvpn-install.sh']
print('start pr')
pr=subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
print(pr.stdout.readline())#количество строк для прочтения может меняться
print(pr.stdout.readline())#количество строк для прочтения может меняться
print(pr.stdout.readline())#количество строк для прочтения может меняться
pr.stdin.write('1\n')
pr.stdin.flush()
print(pr.stdout.readline())
pr.stdin.write('hero\n')
pr.stdin.flush()
print(pr.stdout.readline())#количество строк для прочтения может меняться
print(pr.stdout.readline())#количество строк для прочтения может меняться
print(pr.stdout.readline())#количество строк для прочтения может меняться
```

Хочу реализовать через .communicate()

Comment: Решение перенесите в ответ. В вопросе должен быть только вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---------МОЁ РЕШЕНИЕ---------
Спустя некоторое время я решил проблему иначе. Создав копию установочного скрипта openvpn-install.sh (переименовал в gen_client.sh) я удалил из него все составляющие кроме тех, которые отвечали именно за добавление пользователя. Т.о. мне больше не требовалось делать выбор действия цифрами, а лишь один раз указать имя нового пользователя. После этого новый скрипт отлично заработал через communicate().
Пример скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash
# from
# https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

new_client () {
    # Generates the custom client.ovpn
    {
    cat /etc/openvpn/server/client-common.txt
    echo "<ca>"
    cat /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
    echo "</ca>"
    echo "<cert>"
    sed -ne '/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,$ p' /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/issued/"$client".crt
    echo "</cert>"
    echo "<key>"
    cat /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/private/"$client".key
    echo "</key>"
    echo "<tls-crypt>"
    sed -ne '/BEGIN OpenVPN Static key/,$ p' /etc/openvpn/server/tc.key
    echo "</tls-crypt>"
    } > ~/"$client".ovpn
}

echo
echo "Provide a name for the client:"
read -p "Name: " unsanitized_client
client=$(sed 's/[^0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-]/_/g' <<< "$unsanitized_client")
while [[ -z "$client" || -e /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/pki/issued/"$client".crt ]]; do
    echo "$client: invalid name."
    read -p "Name: " unsanitized_client
    client=$(sed 's/[^0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_-]/_/g' <<< "$unsanitized_client")
done
cd /etc/openvpn/server/easy-rsa/
EASYRSA_CERT_EXPIRE=3650 ./easyrsa build-client-full "$client" nopass
# Generates the custom client.ovpn
new_client
echo
echo "$client added. Configuration available in:" ~/"$client.ovpn"
exit
```

Т.о. в моем python коде это выглядит следующим образом:

```
client=f"hero"
command=[f"sudo bash gen_client.sh"]
pr1=subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
out1=pr1.communicate(f"{client}\n")[0]
print(out1)
```

PS
Также отмечу: очень важно именно отредактировать Ваш файл openvpn-install.sh на рабочей машине, так как он может отличаться от машины, сервера и мест установки программы. На моем сервере и на моем desktop эти файлы значительно отличались, в связи с чем я также потратил некоторое время...